# OC Rollout with specific tag name

Tags: openshift, redhat

I have created Tag Version using oc tag command in CLI, i have to deploy the image with recently created tag version.
Ex. oc tag <Source Service Name>:latest <Destination Service Name>:Rel10.0.
I have created Tag Name as Rel10.0, i have to select this Tag name and deploy it using CLI.

What is OC Command i have to use?

I have tried with `oc rollout latest` but this command does only deploy. I have to select that specific tag name and deploy the image.
 `oc rollout latest <image name>`

I know after doing oc tag in CLI, we can check in Openshift UI for that specific tag name select and deploy it. I dont want to use Openshift i want to use CLI and do this job.

Answer (score 1):

```
oc set image $resourcetype $containername=$imagename:$tag
```

so assuming you have a deployment named web which has a container named server using nginx image you would do the following:

```
oc set image deployment web server=nginx:latest
```

Comment: @James Z - Thanks for above input. 

I have used this command oc set image dc/cc-activation-a:44.0, i am getting error from server that deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io cc-activation-a:44.0 Not found.  

Also tried with oc set image deployment cc-activation-a:44.0 getting deployments.extensions not found error i am getting. 

Can you please some details how to do this with example to understand in better way. 

oc set image $resourcetype cc-activation-a=$imagename:Rel10.0 what i have to give in resource type and imagename?

Comment: @Gopi You are likely using the wrong command. In your case you need to specify both the deployment name and also the container name of the container that you want to change: `oc set image deployment cc-activation-a <CONTAINERNAME>=<IMAGE>:44.0`